# How can I update my new Design changes in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I changed the design and the content in my Wordpress website and when I am logged in it shows me everything correctly. As soon as I enter the URL on Google, the old, un-updated design and content are displayed again and again. So it doesn't update externally if I'm not logged into Wordpress. Where is the mistake? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Likely a caching issue. If you have a caching plugin (eg. W3 Total Cache) flush its cache so your changes are applied to the website right away.

Comment: Try holding the shift key and hitting the refresh button on your browser, to flush your browser cache. If you use a cache plugin, flush that cache. Otherwise you should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.